# How can I supress the Outlook warning while sending mail using macro in excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to send an email using macro in excel.

But when I run this code my mail client i.e. MS Outlook shows a pop up warning similar to
 `Someone is tying to send mail on behalf of you. select yes or no`

Is there any way using [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) to suppress that warning so the email should be sent without any problem?

Comment: Can you please post the code that you are using?

Comment: See http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/security.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way I know is to create an outlook application item, create the message, display the message and use sendkeys to send the message (equivelent of typing alt s).

The drawback is that the sendkeys method can be a bit buggy. To make it more robust I get the inspector for the mail item i.e. the window it is in and activate it immediately prior to the call to sendkeys. The code is shown below:

```
Dim olApp As outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objSentItems As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector

'Check whether outlook is open, if it is use get object, if not use create object
On Error Resume Next
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If olApp Is Nothing Then
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If

Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
objNS.Logon

'Prepare the mail object    
Set objMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With objMail
.To = <insert recipients name as string>
.Subject = <insert subject as string>
.Body = <insert message as string>
.Display   
End With

'Give outlook some time to display the message    
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

'Get a reference the inspector obj (the window the mail item is displayed in)
Set myInspector = objMail.GetInspector

'Activate the window that the mail item is in and use sendkeys to send the message
myInspector.Activate
SendKeys "%s", True
```

I normally then have code to check that the number of items in the sent folder has increased and if not I get the application wait again and repeat the last 2 lines of code and recheck that the number of messages in the sent folder has increased. The code does this upto 5 times. After the 5th time a message box comes up warning that the message may not have been sent.

I have never found this method to fail in sending a message from excel though I once saw the warning message when our system was particularly slow, on investigation it turned out that the message had been sent.

Comment: Does `objMail.GetInspector` still exist? Getting error on the line `The item has been moved or deleted.`

Answer (score 1):

You need use a Redemption DLL to disable this warning...

Download
http://www.dimastr.com/redemption

I Created one way to install this DLL on machine automatic, you can try...

http://www.officevb.com/2011/02/copiando-e-registrando-componentes-na.html

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Julia Grant's Answer
and Answering dsauce

When used Julia' Code directly I got the error `RegisterWindowMessage`
This should be fixed by replacing `Private Declare Function` with `Declare PtrSafe Function`
in the declaration section

```
Option Compare Database
' Declare Windows' API functions
Declare PtrSafe Function RegisterWindowMessage _
        Lib "user32" Alias "RegisterWindowMessageA" _
        (ByVal lpString As String) As Long

 Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" _
            Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As Any, _
            ByVal lpWindowName As Any) As Long


Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" _
        Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
        ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, _
        lParam As Any) As Long

Function TurnAutoYesOn()
Dim wnd As Long
Dim uClickYes As Long
Dim Res As Long
uClickYes = RegisterWindowMessage("CLICKYES_SUSPEND_RESUME")
wnd = FindWindow("EXCLICKYES_WND", 0&)
Res = SendMessage(wnd, uClickYes, 1, 0)

End Function

Function TurnOffAutoYes()
Dim wnd As Long
Dim uClickYes As Long
Dim Res As Long
uClickYes = RegisterWindowMessage("CLICKYES_SUSPEND_RESUME")
wnd = FindWindow("EXCLICKYES_WND", 0&)
Res = SendMessage(wnd, uClickYes, 0, 0)
End Function


Function fEmailTest()

TurnAutoYesOn  '*** Add this before your email has been sent



Set appOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MailOutLook = appOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With MailOutLook
    .To = " <Receipient1@domain.com>;  <Receipient2@domain.com"
    .Subject = "Your Subject Here"
    .HTMLBody = "Your message body here"
    .Send
End With

TurnOffAutoYes '*** Add this after your email has been sent


End Function
```

I know the thread is old, but it may help somebody

Comment: This is not a full answer to the question - if you don't have a full answer, don't post an answer. Instead, you should comment on that other person's answer, once you have the rep.

Comment: As you have noticed, I dont have the rep to comment. So I had to post it as an answer. I was just trying to help people with my small amount of knowledge.

Comment: The solution is not to intentionally violate the rules (which will get you nothing but downvotes and negative attention from moderators), the solution is to get enough rep to comment, and to post full answers in the meantime. StackOverflow isn't a forum.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I will add the Julia's answer to my answer.
sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

I found the code below somewhere on the internet a couple of years ago. It automatically answers 'Yes' for you.

```
Option Compare Database
' Declare Windows' API functions
Private Declare Function RegisterWindowMessage _
        Lib "user32" Alias "RegisterWindowMessageA" _
        (ByVal lpString As String) As Long

 Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" _
            Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As Any, _
            ByVal lpWindowName As Any) As Long


Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" _
        Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
        ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, _
        lParam As Any) As Long

Function TurnAutoYesOn()
Dim wnd As Long
Dim uClickYes As Long
Dim Res As Long
uClickYes = RegisterWindowMessage("CLICKYES_SUSPEND_RESUME")
wnd = FindWindow("EXCLICKYES_WND", 0&)
Res = SendMessage(wnd, uClickYes, 1, 0)

End Function

Function TurnOffAutoYes()
Dim wnd As Long
Dim uClickYes As Long
Dim Res As Long
uClickYes = RegisterWindowMessage("CLICKYES_SUSPEND_RESUME")
wnd = FindWindow("EXCLICKYES_WND", 0&)
Res = SendMessage(wnd, uClickYes, 0, 0)
End Function


Function fEmailTest()

TurnAutoYesOn  '*** Add this before your email has been sent



Set appOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MailOutLook = appOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With MailOutLook
    .To = " <Receipient1@domain.com>;  <Receipient2@domain.com"
    .Subject = "Your Subject Here"
    .HTMLBody = "Your message body here"
    .Send
End With

TurnOffAutoYes '*** Add this after your email has been sent


End Function
```

Comment: it says RegisterWindowMessage is not defined. Do you have the part of the code that manages this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the window is popping up to begin with because the macro is not signed by a Trusted Publisher. This list in your Outlook settings. You must sign the macro and input the signer into your trusted publishers list. Or allow unsigned macros globally.

Answer (score 0):

This Outlook VBA will load an excel file with emails stored as records and send all of them.

```
Option Explicit

 Private Const xlUp As Long = -4162

Sub SendEmailsFromExcel()

    Dim xlApp As Object

    Dim isEmailTo As String    ' Col A
    Dim isSubject As String    ' Col B
    Dim isMessage As String    ' Col C

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim objMsg As MailItem
    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Dim emailsMatrix As Variant

    Dim objWB As Object
    Dim objWs As Object
    Dim FileStr As String

    FileStr = "C:\Users\...\Documents\EmailsInExcel.xlsx"

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("excel.application")

    With xlApp
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    Set objWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileStr)
    Set objWs = objWB.Sheets(1)

    ' Matrix load:  A - Email Address, B - Subject, C - Body
    emailsMatrix = objWs.Range("A1:C" & xlApp.Cells(objWs.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    objWB.Close

    Set objWB = Nothing
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing

'   Done getting Excel emails file.

    For i = 1 To UBound(emailsMatrix)
        isEmailTo = emailsMatrix(i, 1)
        isSubject = emailsMatrix(i, 2)
        isMessage = emailsMatrix(i, 3)


        objMsg.Recipients.Add isEmailTo
        objMsg.Subject = isSubject
        objMsg.Body = isMessage
        objMsg.Send
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked many methods but this is the best.

You just need to create a minimize window code of the Excel and after that maximize it in order to work and also add a little delay after the script hits "Send".

Just make sure to not touch any mouse or  keyboard when it runs. I am able to auto-send 25+ emails without bugs every day.

```
'Excel Minimized
     ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized

'Outlook Email Shown
     .Display
     Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
     Application.SendKeys "%s"
     Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

'Excel Maximized
     ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
```