# Sending emails from Excel using Outlook without security warning

Tags: vba, excel, outlook, excel-2007

I am using code from Ron de Bruin's website to send emails through Excel using Outlook. I get this security warning "A program is trying to send e-mail message on your behalf" asking me to allow or deny.

How can I avoid this warning and send emails directly"

Note: I am using Excel 2007.

Here is the code:

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String
Dim cell As Range

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

Sheets("" & Sheet & "").Select
With Sheets("" & Sheet & "")
    strbody = ""
End With

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = " email1@a.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = ""
    .Body = strbody
    .From = ""
    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

' restore default application behavior
Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=3, Collate:=True
```

Comment: See the answer to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168027/how-can-i-supress-the-outlook-warning-while-sending-mail-using-macro-in-excel/18264196#18264196)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I avoid Outlook's security warning when sending email programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052636/how-can-i-avoid-outlooks-security-warning-when-sending-email-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the methods described in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168027/how-can-i-supress-the-outlook-warning-while-sending-mail-using-macro-in-excel/18264196#18264196) from the comment, assuming you are the sender "...asking me to allow or deny", if you have Excel running you can have Outlook **already** running as well.

The simplest way would be:

```
Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the code below somewhere on the internet a couple of years ago. It automatically answers 'Yes' for you.

```
Option Compare Database
    ' Declare Windows' API functions
    Private Declare Function RegisterWindowMessage _
            Lib "user32" Alias "RegisterWindowMessageA" _
            (ByVal lpString As String) As Long

     Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" _
                Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As Any, _
                ByVal lpWindowName As Any) As Long


    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" _
            Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
            ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, _
            lParam As Any) As Long


    Function TurnAutoYesOn()
    Dim wnd As Long
    Dim uClickYes As Long
    Dim Res As Long
    uClickYes = RegisterWindowMessage("CLICKYES_SUSPEND_RESUME")
    wnd = FindWindow("EXCLICKYES_WND", 0&)
    Res = SendMessage(wnd, uClickYes, 1, 0)

    End Function

    Function TurnOffAutoYes()
    Dim wnd As Long
    Dim uClickYes As Long
    Dim Res As Long
    uClickYes = RegisterWindowMessage("CLICKYES_SUSPEND_RESUME")
    wnd = FindWindow("EXCLICKYES_WND", 0&)
    Res = SendMessage(wnd, uClickYes, 0, 0)
    End Function


    Function fEmailTest()

    TurnAutoYesOn  '*** Add this before your email has been sent



    Set appOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set MailOutLook = appOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With MailOutLook
        .To = " <Receipient1@domain.com>;  <Receipient2@domain.com"
        .Subject = "Your Subject Here"
        .HTMLBody = "Your message body here"
        .Send
    End With

    TurnOffAutoYes '*** Add this after your email has been sent

    End Function
```

Comment: Is this ClickYes application required? http://www.contextmagic.com/express-clickyes/

Comment: No, it is not. I have the blow in my declarations.                              Option Compare Database
Public Declare Function RegisterWindowMessage _
        Lib "user32" Alias "RegisterWindowMessageA" _
        (ByVal lpString As String) As Long

Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" _
        Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As Any, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As Any) As Long
   
Public Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" _
        Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
        ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, _
        lParam As Any) As Long

Comment: @JuliaGrant this still gives a compile error for Option Compare Database , do you have a fix for this?

Comment: Could you add those declarations to your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168027/how-can-i-supress-the-outlook-warning-while-sending-mail-using-macro-in-excel/18264196#18264196) as well?