# Sending email with outlook C#

Tags: c#, email, outlook

Hello I have created an application that will look and see how many hours a plant has run and is designed to send an email to a person that is in charge of tracking all of the pollutants for these plants. my problem is that while it works in Visual Studio once I deploy to the machine it gives me an error.

[image]

If someone could look at the code and tell me where I have an error . Thanks so much.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace RRHoursMgmt
{
    public partial class PlantHoursLookup : Form
    {

        string conn_String = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Y:\\ NotTHISNAME.accdb; Persist Security Info= False";
        string error_msg = "";
        string q = "";

        OleDbConnection conn = null;
        public PlantHoursLookup()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exitt();
        }

        private void connectToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                conn = new OleDbConnection(conn_String);
                conn.Open();
                connectToolStripMenuItem.Text = "\u221A Connected";


                //disToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                //connectToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {


            }
            conn.Close();
        }

        private void disToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Close();
                connectToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Connect";

            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                error_msg = ex.Message;
                MessageBox.Show(error_msg);               

            }

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connectToolStripMenuItem.PerformClick();
            bool isOpen = isOutlookOpen(); // asks if outlook is open returns true or false
            bool shouldWeCloseOutlook = false; // changes to true if we open outlook
            if (isOpen != true)
            {
                openOutlook();
                shouldWeCloseOutlook = true;
            }
            run_Query();
            if (shouldWeCloseOutlook)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
                closeOutlook();  
            }  
            Exitt();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            disToolStripMenuItem.PerformClick();
        }
        private void run_Query()
        {
            error_msg = "";
            q = QueryBox.Text;
            try
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, conn);
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                int i = 0;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                da.Fill(dt);
                Results.DataSource = dt;
                Results.AutoResizeColumns();
                int rowCount = dt.Rows.Count;
                Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
                Outlook.MailItem mi = app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

                string body = "";
                mi.Subject = "Weekly Plant Hours";
                mi.To = "whoever@whatever.com";
                if (rowCount!= 0)
                {
                    //building body string
                    body = "this person, These Plants are over 400 hours:" + Environment.NewLine;
                    for ( i = 0; i < rowCount-1; i++)
                    {
                        body = body + dt.Rows[i][0] + " " + dt.Rows[i][1] + " Hours";
                        body = body + Environment.NewLine;                      

                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    body = body + "this person, There Are no Plants over 400 hours!";
                }
                mi.Body = body.ToString();

                mi.Display(false);
                mi.Send();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                error_msg = ex.Message;
                MessageBox.Show(error_msg);                
            }
        }
        private void runQueryToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            run_Query();
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
        private void Exitt()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
        }
        private bool isOutlookOpen()
        {
            Process[] pName = Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK");
            if (pName.Length == 0)
            {
                return false; 
            }
            return true; 

        }
        private void openOutlook()
        {
            Outlook.Application olook = new Outlook.Application();

        }

        private void closeOutlook()
        {
            Outlook.Application oLook = new Outlook.Application();
            oLook.Quit();

        }  
    }

}
```

Comment: This isn't a debugging service, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168027/how-can-i-supress-the-outlook-warning-while-sending-mail-using-macro-in-excel

Comment: Another option is SmtpClient https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thank you hatchet, Smtp must go through exchange?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I have noticed the following lines of code:

```
Outlook.Application oLook = new Outlook.Application();
oLook.Quit();
```

You need to use an existing instance of the Outlook Application class to call the Quit method, not create a new one.

> my problem is that while it works in Visual Studio once I deploy to the machine it gives me an error.

You get a standard security prompt. "Security" in this context refers to the so-called "object model guard" that triggers security prompts and blocks access to certain features in an effort to prevent malicious programs from harvesting email addresses from Outlook data and using Outlook to propagate viruses and spam. These prompts cannot simply be turned off. There are three main ways to avoid such prompt:

1. The [Security Manager for Outlook](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php) component allows to turn prompts off/on at runtime.
2. Use the low-level code which doesn't generate security prompts. Or any other third-party wrappers around that API (for example, Redemption).
3. Running an up-to-date antivirus software.

You can read more about that in the [Outlook "Object Model Guard" Security Issues for Developers](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52) article.