# How to click "Send Anyway" button in dialog

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I am looking to auto send an Outlook 2013 email from Excel VBA.

I am able to send the email to individuals and pass the TITUS classification.

I get the below error when I send to a **group email address**.
[image]

How do I select "**Send Anyway**" in VBA?

```
Dim AOMSOutlook As Object
Dim AOMailMsg As Object
Set AOMSOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim objUserProperty As Object
Dim OStrTITUS As String
Dim lStrInternal As String
Set AOMailMsg = AOMSOutlook.CreateItem(0)

Set objUserProperty = AOMailMsg.UserProperties.Add("TITUSAutomatedClassification", 1)
objUserProperty.Value = "TLPropertyRoot=ABCDE;Classification=Internal;Registered to:My Companies;"
With AOMailMsg
    .To = "mygroup@list.company.com"
    .Subject = "my subject"
    .Attachments.Add Img
    .HTMLBody = "my text"            
    .Save
    .Send
End With
Set AOMailMsg = Nothing
Set objUserProperty = Nothing
Set AOMSOutlook = Nothing
Set lOMailMsg = Nothing
Set objUserProperty = Nothing
Set lOMSOutlook = Nothing
```

Comment: That looks to be a policy setting within Outlook rather than an issue with programming.  You could use a SendKey..

Comment: Does this window pop up when you place this at the top of your code: `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`? You can set it back to `True` at the bottom of your code.

Comment: @Chrismas007 I'll take a look at SendKey

Comment: @MattCremeens I tried setting DisplayAlerts as False as well as EnableEvents to false, but the alert box still comes up in outlook

Comment: From the image, it appears as though "Send Anyway" is the default, so something like `SendKeys "{ENTER}"` may be enough. You should be made aware, however, that `SendKeys` is notoriously unreliable.

Comment: Also have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168027/how-can-i-supress-the-outlook-warning-while-sending-mail-using-macro-in-excel) if you haven't already

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MattCremeens was able to resolve by adding:

```
    .display
    SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{ENTER}", True 'set classification
    SendKeys "{ENTER}",True 'send to group
    .send
End With
```